# Positioning of divs not working after Parallax implemented

Tags: html, css, css-position, parallax

So i'm relatively new to coding but i've done my research and i haven't been able to find anything that helps me. I'm currently working on a website using parallax and while i got the parallax to work, nothing else is. All other content implemented sticks to the top as if the position is fixed (sans the nav bar, which is intended to be fixed to the top), no matter how many times i change the position or the z-index. Please help, this is starting to feel like a giant mess.

```css
body {
 background-color: #E4DBD6;
}
 
 
 
 

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
}
.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  
}

.parallax__cover {
 background-color: #1A2626;
 position: absolute;
 top: 126%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 7000px;
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(3);
 transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(3);
 bottom: -39%;
}

 
.parallax__layer__1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3);
 transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3);
 left: 440px;
 bottom: -648px;
}


 
.parallax__layer__2 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(1.5);
 transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(1.5);
 bottom: -850px;
 left: 26%;
}
 

  .parallax__layer__center {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-95px) scale(.5);
 transform: translateZ(-95px) scale(.5);
 margin-top: -17%;
 margin-right: -281%;
 bottom: -75%;
 } 
  
 .parallax__layer__logo {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-85px) scale(.5);
 transform: translateZ(-85px) scale(.5);
 left: 53%;
 bottom: 70%;
 } 

.parallax__layer__3 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-75px) scale(1.5);
 transform: translateZ(-75px) scale(1.5);
 bottom: -268px;
 left: 13%;
}
 
.parallax__layer__corner {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-37px) scale(.5);
 transform: translateZ(-37px) scale(.5);
 bottom: -52%;
 right: -1178px;
}


.parallax__layer__4 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) scale(1.2);
 transform: translateZ(-20px) scale(1.2);
 bottom: -47%;
}


.parallax__layer__6 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
 transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
 left: 20%;
 bottom: -59%;
}

 .nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
 font-family: josefin-sans;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 17px;
 background-color: #370215;
 width: 101.6%;
 color: #F3F3F3;
 margin-top: -8.7px;
 left: -32px;
}
 
 h1 {
  z-index: 99; 
  position: relative;
  
 }
 
 #header {
 z-index: 99;
 position: relative;
 }

 
 td#name {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: larger;
 padding-left: 48px;
 }
 
 td#list {
  text-align: right;
 }
 
 
 a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration:.6s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.6s;
    -o-transition-duration:.6s;
 background-color: #3C696F;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-right: 17px;
 padding-bottom: 6px;
 padding-left: 17px;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
 
 a:hover {
 background-color: aliceblue; 
    transition:.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration:.6s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.6s;
    -o-transition-duration:.6s; 
  
}
 

 #trans-nav { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  height: auto; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
 }

 #trans-nav { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  height: auto; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
 }

 #trans-nav li {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
 }

 #trans-nav li:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -40px; 
 }

 #trans-nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #3F121E;
 }

 #trans-nav li a:hover { 
  color: #a3f1d7; 
 }

 #trans-nav li ul { 
  opacity: 0; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 8em; 
  background: #63867f; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
 }

 #trans-nav li:hover ul { 
  opacity: 1; 
 }

 #trans-nav li ul li { 
  float: none; 
  position: static; 
  height: 0; 
  line-height: 0; 
  background: none;
 }

 #trans-nav li:hover ul li { 
  height: 30px; 
  line-height: 30px; 
 }

 #trans-nav li ul li a { 
  background: #63867f; 
 }

 #trans-nav li ul li a:hover { 
  background: #5a8078; 
 }

 #trans-nav li { 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; 
 }

 #trans-nav li a { 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 }

 #trans-nav li ul { 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; 
 }

 #trans-nav li ul li { 
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
 
 
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
    <img src="hills0.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
    <img src="hills1.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
    <img src="hills2.png">
  </div>
  
    <div class=" parallax__layer parallax__layer__center">
   <img src="centerhouse1.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class=" parallax__layer parallax__layer__logo">
   <img src="final.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
    <img src="hills3.png">
  </div>
  
   <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__corner">
   <img src="cornerhousewatercolor.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
    <img src="hills4.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
   <img src="hills5.png">
  </div>
 
  
  <div class="parallax__cover">
  </div>  

</div>

  <div class="nav">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="name" style="text-align: left">the gateways</td>
      <td id="list" style="text-align:center">       
       
   <ul id="trans-nav">
       <li><a href="contact">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">more</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thingamabobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Doohickies</a></li>
            </ul> 
    </li>
      
      <li><a href="computer repairs">computers</a></li>
      <li><a href="signs">signs</a></li>
      <li><a href="printing">printing</a></li>
      <li><a href="home">home</a></li>

       </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
  
  <div id="header">
<h1>header here?</h1>
</div>
```

While the navigation bar is intended to be "fixed" the header and any other content that might be implemented should not be.

Comment: Remove `position: fixed` from `.nav`

Comment: I meant to say that the navigation bar is intended to be fixed, however other content such as #header should not be fixed, yet they're acting like they are.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out! i needed to completely get rid of the .parallax container and just wrap the parallax in the body itself. Unfortunately now i need to go back and adjust everything, but the problem is solved and i can finally move forwards with this thing!